# Como saber quando devo usar um service e o controller?

Tags: java, mvc, arquitetura-de-software, controller, services

Tenho essa duvida desde que conheci o modelo MVC, pois eu fiz uma aplicação onde possuia apenas o model, view e controller, mas eu vejo gente usando o service para "suporte" do controller, e não entendo a diferença dos dois de forma pratica.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, explicando de forma resumida:

**Service**: Seria responsável pelas regras de negócio e as chamadas do DAO ou Repository.

**Controller**: Seria responsável por receber as informações das Views (requisições do usuário) e realizar as chamadas do Service.

Imagine uma aplicação para registro de veículos, a View conteria um formulário que seria preenchido pelo usuário e enviado via requisição HTTP para o Controller, este validaria o formulário e chamaria o Service, que por sua vez conteria a regra de negócio e então enviaria para o DAO ou Repository realizarem as operações no banco de dados.

Espero ter ajudado. :D